# Python super on Meta Class from another class

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

In class Test2 I want to include both the models and fields in its class Meta. Is this possible and how? This is what I have tried...

I have a mixin:

```
class Test1(object):
        pass
    class Meta:
        fields = ("url",)

class Test2(Test1):
        pass
    class Meta:
        super(Meta) <=== does not work
        models= test
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer can be found in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance)

I.E.

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(CommonInfo):
    # ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

Comment: The link is now broken, for 2.2 (LTS): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance, for dev: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance